# Yosemite : change sound output between speaker and headphone

Tags: macos, audio, headphones, speakers

I want to switch between headphones (jack) and internal speakers without having to insert/remove the jack?

Is it possible ? And how ?

Comment: or actually more: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/167531/24324

Comment: Thank you. Did not found this article before posting... So it seems it is not possible :-(